# using @schedule in EJB timer,not able to pass the schedule details from database

Tags: ejb, ejb-timer

using @schedule in  EJB timer, i want to pass the schedule details from database. but it is not allowing passing values. What should i do. In @timeout also i'm not able to start the thread automatically at server start time. @Postconstruct is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use @Timeout, @Singleton, @Startup and @ConcurrencyManagement

```
@Singleton(name = "...", mappedName = "")
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)  // this is threadsafe!!!
public class .......
```

Inject the TimerService for configuration

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService;
```

Inject the EntityManager for db-access

```
@PersistenceUnit(..)
private EntityManager entityManager
```

Use @Timeout instead of @Schedule

```
@Timeout
void timer() { .... }
```

Configure the timer

```
@PostConstruct
void postConstruct() {
   entityManager.createQuery(....);
   .
   .
   timerService.createIntervalTimer(....);
}
```

except usage of EntityManager, this works at our site.

Comment: i dont want to make my class singleton.as it should allow multiple threads for my application.

Comment: using @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)  you can prevent ejb from handling the exclusive accessing of methods. Then you must yourself handle the possible usage by multiple threads.